# Delete all the duplicate values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've tried a lot of solutions, but none of them worked with my case. For example I have 3 arrays (the amount of them can vary from 1 to 4) and I want to delete all the duplicate values from multidimensional array

Example

```
   Array
    (
        [33] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 33
                [name] => Aliquam dolor tellus Aliquam dolor tellus
                [color] => Brown
                [breat] => 3
                [shorten] => Yes
                [material] => Natural
                [rigidity] => Low

        )

    [54] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 54
            [name] => New Style
            [color] => Black
            [breat] => 4
            [shorten] => Yes
            [material] => Natural
            [rigidity] => Low
)
[23] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 23
                [name] => New Natural
                [color] => Yellow
                [breat] => 5
                [shorten] => No
                [material] => Natural
                [rigidity] => Low
    )

    )
```

**And here is the desired array.**

```
 Array
(
    [33] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 33
            [name] => Aliquam dolor tellus Aliquam dolor tellus
            [color] => Brown
            [breat] => 3
            [shorten] => Yes
            [material] =>
            [rigidity] =>

        )

    [54] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 54
            [name] => New Style
            [color] => Black
            [breat] => 4
            [shorten] => Yes
            [material] =>
            [rigidity] =>
)
[23] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 23
                [name] => New Natural
                [color] => Yellow
                [breat] => 5
                [shorten] => No
                [material] =>
                [rigidity] =>
    )

    )
```

Comment: Can you really say those are duplicate values? The `material` and `rigidity` Keys are part of each Sub-Array. Do You want to say that you wish to delete the `material` and `rigidity`  Keys from each sub-array?

Comment: Could you perhaps convert the example array to useable code, for example by using
`var_export()` or preferred `serialize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Logic presented in the Commented Code below to delete the **Keys whose Values are exactly the same in all the Sub-Arrays**. However, The Code below only focuses on 3 Keys namely: `material`, `rigidity`, and `shorten`. If you want to do it for all the Keys, you can simply modify the Code yourself to that effect.

> **NOTE:** All the so-called Duplicates are Deleted... they are not assigned the value of **NULL** as it wouldn't really make much sense but you can also assign them the value of **NULL** if you so choose.

```
    $arr =  [
        33  =>[
            'product_id'=> 33,
            'name'      => 'Aliquam dolor tellus Aliquam dolor tellus',
            'color'     => 'Brown',
            'breat'     => 3,
            'shorten'   => 'Yes',
            'material'  => 'Natural',
            'rigidity'  => 'Low',
        ],
        54  =>[
            'product_id'=> 54,
            'name'      => 'New Style',
            'color'     => 'Black',
            'breat'     => 4,
            'shorten'   => 'Yes',
            'material'  => 'Natural',
            'rigidity'  => 'Low',
        ],
        23  =>[
            'product_id'=> 23,
            'name'      => 'New Natural',
            'color'     => 'Yellow',
            'breat'     => 5,
            'shorten'   => 'No',
            'material'  => 'Natural',
            'rigidity'  => 'Low',
        ],
    ];

    // CREATE TEMPORAL ARRAYS TO HOLD SCALAR VALUES CORRESPONDING TO 
    // THE KEYS WHOSE DUPLICITY YOU WISH TO CHECK.
    // YOU CAN DO THIS FOR ALL THE KEYS IF YOU CHOOSE
    // HERE WE LIMIT THOSE TO THE 3 KEYS BELOW:
    $material = $rigidity = $shorten = [];


    // LOOP THROUGH YOUR ARRAY AND BUNDLE THE VALUES FOR THE 
    // `rigidity`, `shorten` & `material` KEYS INTO UNIQUE ARRAYS 
    // TO BE USED LATER FOR FURTHER PROCESSING *YOUR* DUPLICATES
    foreach($arr as $pid=>$data){
        // ADD THE VALUES OF THE `rigidity`, `shorten` AND `material` KEYS
        // TO THE $rigidity, $shorten AND $material ARRAY RESPECTIVELY:
        $material[] = $data['material'];
        $rigidity[] = $data['rigidity'];
        $shorten[]  = $data['shorten'];
    }

    // EXTRACT THE UNIQUE VALUES OF THE $material, $shorten AND $rigidity ARRAYS
    // THE LENGTHS OF WHICH WE SHALL USE TO DETERMINE IF THEY ARE SAME OR NOT
    // IF THE LENGTH IS 1; THEN THEY ARE THE SAME ACROSS ALL SUB-ARRAY
    // AND THUS ARE FIT TO BE DELETED...
    $material   = array_unique($material);
    $rigidity   = array_unique($rigidity);
    $shorten    = array_unique($shorten);


    // LOOP AGAIN THROUGH YOUR ARRAY BUT THIS TIME
    // ONLY TO DELETE THE KEYS THAT ARE THE SAME ACROSS ALL SUB-ARRAY
    foreach($arr as $pid=>&$data){
        if(count($rigidity) == 1){
            unset($data['rigidity']);
        }
        if(count($material) == 1){
            unset($data['material']);
        }
        if(count($shorten) == 1){
            unset($data['shorten']);
        }
    }
    // CHECK OUT THE CURRENT VALUE OF THE ARRAY YOU STARTED WITH
    var_dump($arr);
```

**THE var_dump($arr) ABOVE YIELDS:**

```
    array (size=3)
      33 => 
        array (size=5)
          'product_id' => int 33
          'name' => string 'Aliquam dolor tellus Aliquam dolor tellus' (length=41)
          'color' => string 'Brown' (length=5)
          'breat' => int 3
          'shorten' => string 'Yes' (length=3)
      54 => 
        array (size=5)
          'product_id' => int 54
          'name' => string 'New Style' (length=9)
          'color' => string 'Black' (length=5)
          'breat' => int 4
          'shorten' => string 'Yes' (length=3)
      23 => 
        array (size=5)
          'product_id' => int 23
          'name' => string 'New Natural' (length=11)
          'color' => string 'Yellow' (length=6)
          'breat' => int 5
          'shorten' => string 'No' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple arrays. But you'd have to loop through twice. Something like this...

```
$array = //your array here

//hold the duplicates and values that exist to a name 
$dupes = $exists = Array();

//get the duplicates
foreach($array as $nextArray)
{
    foreach($nextArray as $key => $val)
    {
        if(!isset($counts[$key])) 
            $counts[$key] = Array($val);
        else {
            //since the key already exists check to see if the value exists
            if(in_array($val,$counts[$key])) {
                if(!isset($dupes[$key]))
                    $dupes[$key] = array($val); 
            }
            else {
                $counts[$key][] = $val;
            }
        }           
    }
}

//apply the duplicates to the array
foreach($array as $arrKey => $nextArray)
{
    foreach($nextArray as $key => $val)
    {
        //if a dupe exist then make the value an empty string
        if(isset($dupes[$key]) && in_array($val,$dupes[$key]))
            $array[$arrKey][$key] = ''; 
    }   
}
```